# Return html from ajax call and format it

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

According to my scenario in my laravel project, A customer can select a date from datepicker. according to the selected date, available times will be display to the customer. I used Ajax to send the selected date to the database, the controller select all available times from database and send back as ajax success data. I hard coded the all time slots as bootstrap radio button group to show the times to customer. I want to disable the buttons with ajax returned times among the button group. how can I change the status of the buttons to disable according to ajax return data. how can I format the html with javascript to perform this?

Datepicker and hard coded button group with time slots.
[image]

Ajax returned times, according to selected date (console log output)
[image]

Ajax code I have used

```
const $datepicker = $('#date').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});

$datepicker.on('changeDate', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/process_date',
        data: {
            date: convert(e.date.toString()),
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    function convert(str) {
        var date = new Date(str),
            month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        return [date.getFullYear(), month, day].join("-");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As API is returning `Date` object, first you have to process `Date` to convert it into time format of 12 Hours, please use `formatDateToTime` to get the correct time, and then you use this value to enable disable radio buttons:

```js
function formatDateToTime(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}
var dt = new Date( "December 25, 1995 23:15:20" );
console.log(formatDateToTime(dt));
```